# Send array from jQuery(ajax) to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

class `email` is an array of email addresses. How do i get the array in jQuery and then send the data with AJAX to send.php along with class `title` and `message`?

```
    <input type='text' size='30' class='email' value='testing1@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' class='email' value='testing2@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' class='email' value='testing3@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' class='title' value='testing title' />
    <input type='text' size='30' class='message' value='testing message' />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var title = $('.title').val();
var message = $('.message').val();

var dataString = 'title=' + title + '&message=' + message;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: dataString,
success:function () {


}

});
});
</script>
```

send.php

```
<?php


  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

foreach($email as $value) {

//send email

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it more simply that [Felix King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944484/send-array-from-jqueryajax-to-php/7944498#7944498), using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), if you name your inputs:

```
<form id="the-form">
    <input type='email' size='30' name="email[]" value='testing1@gmail.com' />
    <input type='email' size='30' name="email[]" value='testing2@gmail.com' />
    <input type='email' size='30' name="email[]" value='testing3@gmail.com' />
    <input type='text' size='30' name='title' value='testing title' />
    <input type='text' size='30' name='message' value='testing message' />
</form>
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: $("#the-form").serialize(),
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: havent tested this but it is a massive time saver.  I've been using longer methods to get values, when all i had to do is give the form an id and use serializearray?

Comment: @user892134: I meant to put `serialize`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var data = {
    title: $('.title').val(),
    message: $('.message').val(),
    email: $('.email').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: data,
    success:function () {

    }
});
```

`data.email` will contain an array of email addresses. jQuery takes care to encode the data properly. See [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: so $email = $_POST['email']; will contain an array?

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work?:

```
var datastring = $('#yourform').serialize();
```

Comment: Not until the `input` elements have `name`s.